# How to export font with "Kern Tables" and not "GPOS Tables" using fontforge?

Tags: fonts, font-design, kerning, font-forge

[image]Font Kerning is not supported on the platform (Unity) when it is in "GPOS Tables" rather it supports "Kern Tables". I have a font in which I've added kerning by classes in Lockups and in matrix window kerning is proper and fine but when I export font as .otf so the kerning is not supported in Unity and MS Word(Softwares I tested).
I did some research and found that Unity supports Kern Tables so  How to export font with "Kern Tables" using fontforge?

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to click on "old type kern" box in options windows in "generate fonts" windows.
[image]